# How can I access specific posts brought back by query_posts?

Tags: loop, query-posts, array

Specifically, I am bringing back the 7 most recent posts in Category A, but then I want to put the first posts thumbnail in `<div id=A>` and the second post's thumbnail in `<div id=B>` and so on for the seven posts.

If this was an array, I would simply use the array position inside of the `<div>`, but I'm not sure how to access the individual posts once I have brought them back with query_posts.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access to Instance Variables from WP\_Query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110607/access-to-instance-variables-from-wp-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a counter and then conditional logic?

```
$i = 0;
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    if($i === 0){
        echo '<div class="a">'.other_stuff().'</div>';
    } elseif($i === 1){
        echo '<div class="b">'.other_stuff().'</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="default">'.other_stuff().'</div>';
    }
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: `$loop->current_post` prevent the use of `$i` and a `switch` statement normally is faster than seven `if / elseif`

Comment: Thanks, G.M. That might work as I could also inject other HTML around each of the if/then or switchs. I will try it and get back.

Comment: seven? i was told 2! and i've never had an issue using `$i`

Comment: I actually meant, thanks to GhostToast and G.M. GT, "7" is in the first sentence. I'm actually working on combining both of ideas.

Comment: @GhostToast `$i` is so innocent... I don't think it can ever bring an issue, the mine was just a tip, because `current_post` is so *comfortable*

Answer (score 2):

First, in general it's better to use WP_Query vs query_posts as query_posts modifies the main loop while WP_Query generates a secondary loop and causes less messiness later on.

PHP will also advance alpha variables for you with a simple `++`.  For example:

```
$div_id = 'a';
$div_id++; // $div_id now equals 'b'
```

For your example:

```
$args = array("your args here");
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
$div_id = 'a';
if($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while($my_query->have_posts()) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        echo '<div id="'.$div_id.'">'.the_content().'</div>';
        $div_id++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I know that I can loop through with the 'while' and output seven identical html code blocks. However, div A is somewhere on the page and div B is somewhere else on the page surrounded by a different html block and div C is surrounded by yet a different html block. So I thought it would be easiest to access it like an array DivA=arr[1].the_title, (that is shorthand html!). Also thanks for the heads up on WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

just to add to the answers already here, there's no reason why you have to output results within a control structure. `the_post()` is what advances the internal `current_post` counter and sets up the global `$post` variable with the current post's data. with this in mind, you can access any post within a query's results in any order-

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$query->the_post();

the_content(); // outputs content from first post

$query->the_post();

the_content(); // outputs content from second post

$query->current_post = -1;

$query->the_post();

the_content(); // outputs content from first post again

$query->current_post = 8;

$query->the_post();

the_content(); // outputs content from 10th post
```

Comment: Thank you, Milo. I will have to take a look at this and reformat my code as needed. It seems like what I needed (but was already well underway with the other solution)